# Select audio track in HLS Stream using MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play HLS stream. I can chose between subtitles, but I don't know how to select audio tracks. Video has several audio tracks (e.g. in VLC I can select them).

How can I get all audio tracks and select them during playing video?